# Get element by tag name and class name

Tags: javascript

(in vanilla JavaScript) I was wondering if the was an easy way to do something like

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('span') && getElementsByClassName('null');
```

To return all 'span' elements that have the class name 'null'?

I thought it might have been something like:

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); 
x = x.getElementsByClassName('null');
// or     
x = document.getElementsByTagName('span').getElementsByClassName('null');
```

But that didn't seem to work out.

Is this possible or will I have to iterate through x popping anything that returns false for .class='null'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The DOM does not provide any APIs for filtering NodeLists.

Instead, you can use CSS selectors:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('span.null');
```

Comment: [Obligatory support matrix](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) — although it's pretty well supported :-)

Comment: Owww, CSS selectors! Where have you been all my life :P

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp